# Extracting specific string from string (regexp?)

Tags: regex

I am writing a sort of instruction string parser for a project so that users can write "instructions" to do things.

So some example "Instructions"

```
ADD 5 TO 3
FLY TO MOON
GOTO 10 AND MOVE 50 PIXELS
```

I assign these to an array of strings

```
var Instructions = ["ADD * TO *","FLY TO *", "GOTO * AND MOVE * PIXELS"];
```

If I have some:

```
var input = // String
```

And that string could be something like `ADD 5 to 8` or `FLY TO EARTH`

Is there a regexp search of match I could use to help me find which instruction matched? For example

```
var numInstructions = Instructions.length;
for (var j = 0; j < numInstructions; j++)
{
     var checkingInstruction = Instructions[j];
     // Some check here with regexp to check if there is a match between checkingInstruction and input
     // Something like... 
     var matches = input.match(checkingInstruction);
     // ideally matches[0] would be the value at the first *, matches[1] would be the value of second *, and checkingInstruction is the instruction that passed
}
```

Comment: You would need to give all possible commands and operators before anyone can give a "regex" which would actually just turn into a parser.

Comment: @ShoMinamimoto I was hoping that there's be some wild card character that could replace the X and Ys.

Comment: Well then you need to define a grammar and possible inputs. Are X and Y integers? Characters? Words with spaces? Can commands have integers, symbols, etc? (like is there a command that is called MOVE52). Define what exactly you want to capture and what you don't.

Comment: @ShoMinamimoto Ideally just strings (with no spaces if that makes it easier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this.

```
//setup
var instruction_patterns = [/ADD (\w+) TO (\w+)/, /FLY TO (\w+)/],
    input = "ADD 4 TO 3",
    matches;

//see if any instructions match and capture details
for (var i=0, len=instruction_patterns.length; i<len; i++)
    if (matches = input.match(instruction_patterns[i]))
        break;

//report back
if (matches)
    alert(
        '- instruction:\n'+matches[0]+'\n\n'+
        '- tokens:\n'+matches.slice(1).join('\n')
    );
```

Note the patterns are stored as REGEXP literals. Also note that, despite the comment in your original code, `matches[0]` will always be the entire match, so this cannot be the first token (4). That will be in `matches[1]`.

I have assumed in the patterns that the tokens could be anything alphanumeric (`\w`), not necessarily numbers. Adjust this as required.

Finally, to allow case-insensitive, just add the `i` flag after each pattern (`/pattern/i`).